# What does the jekyll command bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental mean?

Tags: bundle, jekyll, github-pages

What does the jekyll command:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental
```

mean and how can I make it rebuild only those pages that I have modified/ updated rather than building the entire site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bundle exec` looks for a [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.15/man/gemfile.5.html) in your current directory, you should run that in Jekyll root folder.

If you don't have a Gemfile then you can create one with `bundle init` and adding the gems you need.

`jekyll serve` serves your site locally for development purposes.

Finally, the `--incremental` flag does what you need:

> only re-builds posts and pages that have changed

Comment: without --incremental, it shows in terminal the changed files with `regenerating: ...`, and builds the _site folder new. With --incremental, it does the same, putting a new timestamp on the _site folder's files.